# How can I check if string contains character using ASSERT?

Tags: c

How can I check if string contains character using ASSERT? For example, I want to do something with my string only if I have '+' in it. How can I do using assert in C?

Comment: I don't think you want to use assert here at all. Assert is used to enforce valid conditions, which are programing errors when they are false. Assertions help to find bugs. They are _not_ used to test user input.

Comment: I recommend to check out assert man page. it is ment to be a diagnostics tool:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_macro_assert.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strchr` along with `assert` function.

```
char x[20] = "hello+"; 

assert(strchr(x,'+') != NULL);
```

`strchr(x,'+')` will return `NULL` if character is not found in the `string` hence you can use the its return value to `assert`.

According to [assert man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/assert.3.html)

> If expression is false (i.e., compares equal to zero), assert()
>          prints an error message to standard error and terminates the program
>          by calling abort(3).  The error message includes the name of the file
>          and function containing the assert() call, the source code line
>          number of the call, and the text of the argument; something like:

And according to [strchr man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strchr.3.html)

> The strchr() and strrchr() functions return a pointer to the matched
>              character or NULL if the character is not found.  The terminating
>              null byte is considered part of the string, so that if c is specified
>              as '\0', these functions return a pointer to the terminator.

Comment: And even further down on `asset()`'s man-page: "*assert() is implemented as a macro; if the expression tested has
       side-effects, program behavior will be different depending on whether
       NDEBUG is defined.  This may create Heisenbugs which go away when
       debugging is turned on.*"